# Ansible: Copy file on all the servers except on server which are not part of specific Group(2)

Tags: ansible

I have more than 200 servers on which i have to copy the Repo file and what i dont want is to copy the file on e.g AppCluster and DBCluster servers. Because Clusters have different Repo files and Standard have different Repo file

```
[AppCluster]
172.16.55.5
172.16.55.6
172.16.55.7
172.16.55.8

[DBCluster]
172.16.56.5
172.16.56.6
172.16.55.7
172.16.55.8
```

I tried

> ```
> - name: Copy YUM File                                                                  
>   copy:                                                                                
>     src: /home/sysadmin/ansible_files/modules_utils/templates/repofile/rhel-remote.repo
>     dest: /etc/yum.repos.d/                                                            
>     owner: root                                                                        
>     group: root
>
>     mode: '0644'
>   when: ansible_distribution_major_version == "7" and (group_names != "AppCluster" or group_names != "DBCluster")
> ```

But it doesn't seem to work

Any advice

Answer (score 2):

Q: ***"Don't copy the file on AppCluster and DBCluster servers."***

A: Try this condition

```yaml
  when:
    - ansible_distribution_major_version == '7'
    - group_names|intersect(['AppCluster', 'DBCluster'])|length == 0
```

---

**Example**

Given the inventory

```
shell> cat hosts 
srv1
srv2
srv3

[AppCluster]
srv2

[DBCluster]
srv3
```

The playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "Copy repo to {{ inventory_hostname }}"
      when: group_names|intersect(['AppCluster', 'DBCluster'])|length == 0
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i hosts pb.yml 

PLAY [all] ********************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************
skipping: [srv3]
ok: [srv1] => 
  msg: Copy repo to srv1
skipping: [srv2]

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************
srv1: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
srv2: ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0   
srv3: ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could just exclude the groups with host.

hosts:

```
all
!AppCluster
!DBCluster
```

Comment: ironically , i used the same solution in another playbook, Thanks for reminding me

Comment: I think it's a touch faster to use the hosts as Ansible won't need to do anything on the excluded servers.   With that said it depends on the number of excluded servers if it will make a big enough difference in run time.